# How to convert the table data to publish to TP again in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I would like to run a test.

Need to convert the current kdb table and publish in the existing TP again so it will push to the existing rdb. For example: I have this table

```
tab:([]sym:100?`AAPL`MSFT`GOOG;price:100?100.0)
```

How do I convert and push from TP to rdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you could send something like this to your tickerplant:

```
h:hopen`:<tphost>:<tpport>:<user><pass>;
neg[h](`.u.upd;`tableName;value flip delete time from tableName)
```

assuming that your tickerplant adds a time column so it needs to be deleted again prior to sending back to it (by default a tickerplant wants to add a time column). Though if you want to retain the time from the original data and not have the tickerplant add a new timestamp then you could do:

```
neg[h](`.u.upd;`tableName;value flip tableName)
```

But a few things to note:

1. The tickerplant is likely going to log this data again to the tickerplant log. Meaning that your log would have duplicate data if it was replayed
2. If you're going to retain the time from the injected data and not allow the TP to add a new timestamp (as mentioned above) then the time order of your tickerplant log is going to look a bit off
3. All other subscribers to the TP will get this duplicate data again, not just the RDB.
4. A vanilla tickerplant might expect a specific schema starting with `` `time`sym `` as the first two columns so if your table has been altered in any way you might need to reshape it